# Can a quantum computer (theoretically) do things a classical computer (literally) can't?

Tags: computability, undecidability, computation-models, quantum-computing

I've been searching the net for an answer to this question, but it's guetting quite confusing.
I want to know if there are some [undecidable problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_undecidable_problems#Problems_in_logic) for a classical computer that a quantum computer could do.
The examples I've seen are things like [Shor's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm), but that's "just" because the quantum computer is more powerfull than the classical one, and can do stuff like Integer factorization faster. Or at least that's how I understand it so far.
Basically my question is this : is there anything a quantum computer can do that a regular one can't if said regular computer had infinite power (or processing speed or whatever)?
Examples, explanations, sources would be greatly appreciated, but a simple yes/no would please me also.

Comment: "said regular computer had infinite power (or processing speed or whatever)"  You mean a Turing Machine?

Comment: It might depend what you mean by "things". We typically think of simply computing an input on an output, in which case the answer is "no" in that a classical computer can simulate the quantum one (it might take a long time though). However, I (non-expert) feel like I have heard the answer could be "yes" if the thing we want to do involves a system or network of computers and quantum entanglement/randomness is involved. For instance, playing some guessing game with probability higher than any classical computer could.

Comment: E.g. "quantum advantages for classically defined tasks" http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.77.052310

Comment: this was a pretty good question until that phrase "...if said regular computer had infinite power or processing speed or whatever" which unf doesnt make much scientific sense, its a [counterfactual](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_conditional)

Answer (score 13):

No. Quantum computers cannot solve undecidable problems.

A quantum computer can be simulated by a classical computer. So, if a quantum algorithm could solve an undecidable problem, then we could also solve it classically via simulation.  However, we already know that if a problem has no classical solution, then it must not have a quantum solution either.

Also, you said:

> that's "just" because the quantum computer is more powerful than the classical one.

This is an open problem.  We do not yet know if $BPP \subset BQP$.

Answer (score -2):

I quantum computer isn't more powerful than a classical one, according to [Church-Turing's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis) thesis, a function on the natural numbers is computable if and only if it is computable by a Turing machine, that means that there isn't a computer model that is more powerful than a Turing Machine.

Comment: The Church-Turing Thesis is a _conjecture_ about the nature of mechanical computability. [There are plenty of models that exceed the power of Turing Machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation). Whether these are physically realizable is a different argument, but the models exist.